# batch execute_write to neo4j with Python SDK

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I aim to iterate through a dataframe to extract values, then create multiple Node in a batch manner to neo4j via the Python SDK. However, execute_write seems to allow on a single statement per query `{code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 3542` (there are 3542 rows in my df)

My attempt:

```
def create_Person(tx, df):
    query_string = """"""
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        query_string = query_string + f"""
        MERGE (l:Person {{id: "{row['col']}"}})
        SET l.name = "{row['col1']}",
            l.Person_Type = "{row['col2']}";
    """
    return tx.run(query_string)

with neo4j_driver.session() as session:
    # Run the unit of work within a Read Transaction
    result = session.execute_write(create_Person, df)
    session.close()
```

Comment: can you print the output of `query_string` & also run that in in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is the best but this works for me:

```
with neo4j_driver.session() as session:
# Run the unit of work within a Read Transaction
with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        tx.run(f"""
    MERGE (l:Person {{id: "{row['col']}"}})
    SET l.name = "{row['col1']}",
        l.Person_Type = "{row['col2']}";
                """)
    tx.commit()

session.close()
```